# Analytic solution to the finite Heisenberg chain without periodic boundary conditions

Tags: quantum-spin

Consider the hamiltonian of a ferromagnetic finite Heisenberg chain for spin $1/2$ of $N$ sites:
$$\hat{H} = -J \sum_{j=1}^{N-1}\hat{S}_j \cdot \hat{S}_{j+1}.$$
If we fix periodic boundary conditions, that is, we add the term $J\hat{S}_1 \cdot \hat{S}_N$ then the Bethe Ansatz gives the solutions that has been known for about 90 years, that is, that this hamiltonian has eigenvalues
$$E_n = E_0 + J \left(1- \cos \left( \dfrac{2 \pi n}{N} \right) \right),$$
which is based on trying out translation invariant wavefunctions and block-diagonalizing the hamiltonian using that $S_z$ is a good quantum number.
The lack of translation symmetry seems to make unfeasible the same approach for the finite chain.
**Is there anyway then to get analytic results for the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the aperiodic finite Heisenberg chain?**

Comment: You might be unclear about what [Bethe ansatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bethe_ansatz) actually does - what you quote here is a result for tight-binding approximation, which is solvable without difficulties for a finite chain (a discrete limit of an infinite quantum well.) I suggest adding more details, to clarify the question.

Comment: Comments, not answers: Bethe ansatz only works for the S=1/2 Heisenberg chain, you have only listed $n$ eigenvalues whereas the Hamiltonian has $2^n$ - these are not sums of single particle energies in the interacting case, I believe the Bethe ansatz (or at least its algebraic variant) still works for open boundary conditions it is just more work.

Comment: True @jacob1729, I meant S=1/, I will edit the question now.

Comment: And @Roger Vadim, I don't know what you mean, sorry, the $J(1-\cos(2\pi /N))$ is the exact spectral gap for the many-body finite periodic Heisenberg chain, as can be checked also numerically

Comment: Your expression for the 'eigenvalues' is still not an expression for all the eigenvalues, only $n$ of them - in the ferromagnet these are the first excited states but in the antiferromagnet (which you seem to be considering) they are highly excited

Comment: Thank you, you are right that I was implicitly assuming a ferromagnetic interaction and I was a bit slopy with that. I added that to the question, I think nothing's missing now. As for the eigenvalues, certanly I didn't pretend to encompass all of them (anyway, many are degenerate, so there are far more than $n$ states associated to those $n$ eigenvalues, by no means there are $2^n$ different eigenvalues, as you seemed to imply in your fisrt message).